# jQuery hide not working on mobile phone

Tags: jquery

I have a form that I am trying to hide upon submission and then to show a div that has a success message in it in place of the form.

My issue is the form works on deestop. However on mobile phone jquery does not seem to be hiding the form and showing the success message div
Here is my code

For the form

```
<div class="success" style="display:none; color:#ffffff; font-weight:bold; padding:10px 0 30px;">
    Email Address Saved
</div>
<form method="POST" action="http://www.kissusa.com/z-ajax/newsletter-ajax.php" class="myForm">
    <input type="email" name="email" class="input-text" placeholder="ENTER EMAIL">
    <input id="bottomSignUp" type="submit" name="subscribe" value="SIGN UP">
</form>
```

My jquery

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery(".myForm").ajaxForm(function(){
            jQuery(".success").show();
            jQuery(".myForm").hide();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I updated the code cleared cache but still not working?

Comment: @user1739740 fixed some syntax errors via editing, that should take the obvious out of the way

Comment: @AGE please do not fix syntax errors while editing because sometimes they are the issues. The original code should not be changed other than formatting. not that it makes a difference in this case

Comment: Well my code looks like the above yet on mobile the form is not getting hidden and success div not being shown once the form is submitted. yet on desktop it works as it is suppose to?

Comment: @Huangism noted, I did consider that in my editing which is why I know that it did not solve the question and leaves it open to others to contribute without having to withdraw from helping from seeing simple syntax errors, now they can focus instead on the fix at hand

Comment: Can you confirm that the function is even getting called? Maybe use `ajaxForm`'s `success` and `error` callbacks as options, instead, to verify.

Comment: I am not sure what would make the function not be called on mobile when it works on desktop

Comment: I just copied the source and uploaded it to my private server and it works just fine on mobile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use classes to control styling and layout.  That way you can apply it where needed and it is maintainable.

**CSS:**

```
/* style is what will hide elements */
.hide {
    left: -9999px !important;
    position: absolute !important;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: -500;
    top: -9999px;
}

.success {
    color: #ACE;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: solid 1px blue;
    width: 250px;
    padding: 30px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #FFF;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: .93em;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="success hide">Email Address Saved</div>
<form method="POST" action="http://www.kissusa.com/z-ajax/newsletter-ajax.php" class="myForm">
    <input type="email" name="email" class="input-text" placeholder="ENTER EMAIL">
    <input id="bottomSignUp" type="submit" name="subscribe" value="SIGN UP">
</form>
```

**jQuery:**

```
jQuery('form:first').ajaxForm({
    success: show_success
});

function show_success() {
    jQuery('.success.hide').removeClass('hide');
    jQuery('.myForm').addClass('hide');
    console.log('hello');
}
```

This solution was inspired by whomever created the jsfiddle located at:
http://jsfiddle.net/hRTcE/

I had no prior knowledge of the ajaxForm library or methods prior to this post.

[Working jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/dixalex/vt587wLh/)

Comment: Why dont you use display:none; for the hide class?

Comment: @flosommerfeld It comes down to preference, but there are certain events that get lost when an element has display none.  It probably does not apply to this specific scenario, but an alternative method should be noted and publicized.